# Foundation 6 - how can I stick a row under top-bar?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have a sticky `top-bar`, ie something like:

```
<div id="main-navigation" class="top-bar-container" data-sticky-container>
    <div class="sticky sticky-topbar" data-sticky data-options="anchor: page; marginTop: 0; stickyOn: small;">
        <div class="top-bar">
            <div class="top-bar-left">
                <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
                    <li class="menu-text">
                        <strong>My Brand</strong>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now I have a `row` that I want to stick to it, but it does not work properly (it sticks to the top of the page when I scroll):

```
<div class="filter-row row" data-sticky-container>
    <div class="sticky column expanded" data-sticky data-top-anchor="main-navigation:bottom">

    </div>
</div>
```

P.S.: the `main-navigation` sticks properly.

Comment: what about the css that goes along ? is the right behind #main-navigation or else where down the page ? ... can you clarify and share enough code that shows your issue ? is the sticky position handled via js or CSS (`position:sticky;` + coordonates where & when to stick)

Comment: @GCyrillus It is `sticky` SCSS that is provided by Foundation framework - ie. http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html . The main-navigation stays on top when scrolling as expected, but the `row` stays on top of page (literally), instead of just under the main-navigation. Basically they overlap each other now.